# UIAutomation pinch simulation

Tags: iphone, pinch, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to build a testing script for my iPhone application. Inside this test, I'm trying to simulate a pinch action.
I read on the official Apple reference that is possible to call the *pinchOpenFromToForDuration* function of *UIATarget*, but the simulator responds to this action how a double tap action (I'm sure because with double tap i perform another action in my code).
I can't understand how I can solve this problem, is possible to use any other trick to reach the same result?

Thank's
   Marco

Answer (score 1):

The odd behavior you are experiencing very well could be the coordinates you are using for the `pinchOpenFromTo` operation.

If the coordinates translate to something that does not "pinch" - like a WebView - then you usually get the click or tap result you mention.  That has been my experience, anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Use UIGestureRecognizer class for the zooming functionality. It would be easy for you to handle.
If you are in need of Pinch gesture use UIPinchGestureRecognizer class and delegate to handle that. 
For Tap you may use UITapGestureRecognizer class and delegate methods….

Comment: My post refers to UIAutomation testing, not on the objective-c implementation.